# SharePoint 2007 alerts

Tags: list, calendar, alert

is it possible to cretae alert in calendar list for:
The person that created the meeting (item) will automatically receive notification when there is a change?

Answer (score 1):

Create a view with a filter of Created By is equal to [Me]. Then set up the alert for when exsisting items are modified.

However this would mean setting up an alert for each person who can create calendar events.

An easier way would be to use a SharePoint Designer workflow which runs on item modified and e-mails the person in the created by field.

Comment: The view alert won't work on SP 2007 (cf. question title).

Comment: @Christophe Sorry, what do you mean? I use 2007 and I've set up view alerts before

Comment: You can't setup an alert on a view that uses filters like [Me].

Comment: @Ryan You can, I've just tested it on a list. The view is filtered to show events created by [Me]. I modified an entry and the e-mail came through...

Comment: Sorry, I spoke too fast! But it doesn't seem to work for me on a calendar list.

Comment: @Enilorac In your test, you would receive the e-mail even if the view filter didn't work!

Comment: That said, you can create an alert for: Alert Me When Someone else changes an event created by me. No need to create a specific view.

Comment: I create Calendar view. I filter the view like that: Show item only when column created by [me]. now I create alert: Action-> alert me. in the "Send alert To" field I need to write spesific name. but I dont wont to write spesific name I want to send alert to the user how create this item. I dont understand how to do it?....

Comment: You need to set up the alert for  each person individually or use another program. It's very easy to set up an alert like this in SharePoint Designer